# InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

Tags: mysql

Since a few weeks that I have added a wordpress site to my server (lamp), which runs a few other, website mysql keeps crashing every once in a while.
The mysql log contains:

```
InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

Which indicates that I do not have enough memory.

The server has 1gb ram and if im right it contains 2gb swap:

[image]

the innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128.0M

The traffic on the server is low, around 150 visitors per day combined for the websites.

I know I could lower the inno_db_buffer_size but that dosnt solve the high memory usage.

Im suspecting wordpress to be the cause since it started after adding the wordpress site. How can I detect the cause of the error to avoid mysql from crashing.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, MySQL, WordPress, etc. are you running?

Comment: @FCTW ubuntu 14.04, wordpress 4.7, mysql 5.5.43

Comment: You need more memory. What's interesting though, is that you're not using any swap space. You might try setting vm.swappiness=90 and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, what is the ratio of your InnoDB log file size to your InnoDB Buffer pool size?  What about your InnoDB buffer pool as compared to your data size?

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that you may want to check out the 'MySQL Tuner' at https://raw.github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

Comment: @fctw this screenshot is after a server reboot thats why swap is empty i gues. How do you know the Memory is used by MySQL and not dor example Apache?

Comment: @heynnema this is after a reboot most likely thats why swap is empty. Yes but why do i need more memory thats my question. I think it would be better to find the cause of the lack of available memory than to just add memory.

Comment: It would be better to see the `free -m` command closer to when you get the memory allocate error. As I mentioned, you might try vm.swappiness to see if that gives you the required buffer space.

Comment: @heynnema swap is definetly used see my other qustion on askubunt about Memory for the screenshots. I dont know when the server is gone crash it is random.

Comment: Give me a link to your other question...

Comment: @heynnema http://askubuntu.com/questions/851690/should-used-memory-lower

Comment: The free images that I saw there looked pretty normal. You still might try setting vm.swappiness as I suggested earlier and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat after me:

**MySQL is not crashing.**

This is a common condition, and "crashing" is a common misconception... but in reality, MySQL is almost certainly *being killed* by the system because of a severe low-memory condition, usually caused by Apache.

```
sudo egrep 'kernel|oom' /var/log/syslog
```

Note that this is not a crash:

```
InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

This is MySQL unable to restart even though it tries to recover after being killed, because there *still* isn't 128 MB of free memory on the server, due to the apache children consuming it all.

After a reboot, nobody's connected to your web site, so the memory problem is gone.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25083/11651

You need more memory, or you need to run Apache and MySQL on different machines, or you need to configure Apache to demand less memory under load.

And for the love of a that is good and right, *never* use mysqltuner or anything similar. They make guesses, they give bad advice, and they are not your friend.  Leave MySQL default values as they are.